# Can I chain a substring check in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code:

```
if (store.getItem('TopicID') != "00")
```

TopidID is always 4 digits and what I need to do is change this to check if the last two digits are "00".

Can I do this as part of the above by just adding ".substring(from, to)" or do I need to put this into a variable and then check the variable?

Comment: `TopicID` is always 4 digits or `store.getItem('TopicID')` return string that always 4 digits length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I do this as part of the above by just adding ".substring(from, to)"

Yes, you can. You got the wrong syntax, though.

```
if (store.getItem('TopicID').substring( 2 ) != "00")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `if (!/00$/.test(store.getItem('TopicID'))` to check for the last 2 digits not forming '00'. That way the length of the value of `store.getItem('TopicID')` doesn't matter, you always check for the last two characters of the value, and you don't need the `substring`  'chaining'.

By the way, I supposed `store.getItem('TopicID')` returns a `String` here.

To be complete and in response to Paul Phillips comment: in `!/00$/.test([somestring])`, `/00$/` is a [Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), a special text string for describing a search pattern. In this case it means: for the string resulting from `store.getItem('TopicID')`, check if you can find 2 consecutive zero's, where the `$`-sign means 'check for that pattern at the end of the string'.

To be even more complete on the subject of 'chaining': as long as a method is contained by the object to chain, everything can be chained. A completely nonsensical example of that:

```
Number(/00$/.test('0231')) //convert a boolean to a Number
 .toFixed(2)               //a Number has the toFixed method
 .split('.')[1]            //toFixed returns a String, which has method split
 .substr(1)                //the second element is a string, so substr applies
 .concat(' world')         //still a string, so concat will do
 .split(' ')               //string, so split works
 .join(' hello ')          //from split an array emerged, so join applies
;
//=> result of this chain: '0 hello world'
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained why that makes sense.

Comment: I meant the use of regular expressions. Someone who is unsure of chaining probably doesn't know an advanced topic like that.

Comment: @Paul: would you think there is enough explanation now?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) or [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) with negative *start*:

```
if ( store.getItem('TopicID').substr(-2) !== "00" ){...}
```

or

```
if ( store.getItem('TopicID').substring(-2) !== "00" ){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chaining it would work.  So would extracting a local variable. So no, you don't *need* to. Do it if you think it makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

you can do using `slice` too

```
if (store.getItem('TopicID').slice(2,4) != "00") {
      // Do Your Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's four digits, you can use

```
if (store.getItem('TopicID') % 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var yourString = (store.getItem('TopicID'))
 if(yourString.substring((yourString.length - 2), 2) == "00")
```

The code above doesn't care how long your string is. It gets the last two digits and compare to "00"